# Can Sidekiq take advantage of multiple CPU cores?

Tags: ruby, amazon-ec2, imagemagick, sidekiq

I am new to Sidekiq and use it with Ruby on Amazon EC2 instances to do some work using ImageMagick with images.

While running it I realized that every worker runs on the same core. I use EC2 c3.2xlarge machines and they have 8 cores. It shows CPU usage is 15% but one core used 100%, and the others are using 0%.

Can Sidekiq use different CPU cores for different workers? If it can, is this inefficiency caused by ImageMagic and how can I make it to use other cores?

Comment: What version of Ruby are you running? 1.8 was stuck in a single core. Ruby's threading model is changing, but for now it has limitations that keep it from providing full threading, like we'd see in Java or other languages. See the "Types of Threads in Different Ruby Versions" section in http://www.sitepoint.com/threads-ruby/ for a nice summary.

Comment: I am using ruby version 1.9.3 . I want to use 2.0.0 but elasticbeanstalk does not support it yet

Answer (score 20, accepted):

If you want to utilize multiple cores using MRI, you'll need to start multiple Sidekiq processes; having multiple threads configured for your sidekiq instance is not enough.

So if you wanted to use all 8 cores, you would start 8 processes. They will all feed off of the same queue, so there's no need to worry about jobs being processed multiple times.

Comment: So If I understand it correctly I basically need to do bundle exec sidekiq for 8 cores and it will just read the same config/sidekiq.yml?